# On Premise CRM 2016 Solutions import causes multiple server errors and sluggish performance client side

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm, sql-server-performance

On Premise CRM 2016 Solutions import causes multiple server errors and sluggish performance client side

Multiple solution update to live CRM server via solution import causes:

1. Sluggish behaviour in Front end CRM
2. MSCRMAsyncService$Maintenance errors in event log
3. Reporting Server Windows Server errors in event log
4. Application Error errors in event log
5. MSCRMWebService errors in event log
6. MSCRMPlatform errors in event log
7. Long running script errors in IE11
8. Invalid user authorization errors moving between forms

The above issues are fixed with a reboot of the server.

This is issue in intermittent as it doesn't occur with every publish of solutions.

Comment: I'm confused -- what is your specific question?

Comment: Read it slower.